# PHP script to download the content of the page into PDF Format

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, yii, phpmyadmin

I have used below code, it was working fine but the PDF is not opening, it shows the below message.

> Acrobat could not open 'excel.php-2.pdf' because it is either not a
> supported file type or because the file has been damaged (*e.g., it
> was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded*).
>
> To create an Adobe PDF document, go to the source application. Then
> choose Save as Adobe PDF from the PDF dropdown in the Print dialog."

```
<?php
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    
    // It will be called downloaded.pdf
    header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="downloaded.pdf"');
    
    // The PDF source is in original.pdf
    readfile("original.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So erm... is the pdf called "downloaded.pdf", "original.pdf", or "excel.php-2.pdf"?

Comment: show full code in question

Comment: Thank you reply guys, I just used the above code to download the content of the PHP file into the pdf format. And my question is when i try to open that pdf file it showing the below error.                "Acrobat could not open 'downloaded.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (e.g., it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

To create an Adobe PDF document, go to the source application. Then choose Save as Adobe PDF from the PDF dropdown in the Print dialog.

Comment: Some servers, where PDF is not registered as a mime type, will not trigger the file download prompt in the browser and write the PDF as plain text.You are better off with "application/octet-stream" mimetype. The browser usually has better intelligence and launch the PDF reader based on the file extension.

Comment: @gn1 Thanks for your reply,   I changed "application/pdf" to "application/octet-stream" then also same error.           The pdf file is downloading, but when i try to open the pdf file at that time it shows error

Comment: It seems that the original.pdf itself is corrupt. Unless it is a dynamically generated PDF, you can simply link to it using a HTML link tag.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that simple, what you would need to do is run the HTML source through a file which converts html to pdf. A good tool for this is the fpdf library. Then output it with a force download flag.